# Expense Management with Diwali-to-Diwali Diary

Tags: lakshmi, kubera

This question can be asked in many different ways, and can be a fit for many different sites on the Stack Exchange network, but I think it is best fit for this site.

I wanted to better manage my day-to-day expenses, and combining it with my (continued) exploration of Indian culture, I decided to try out something called a Diwali-to-Diwali diary:

[image]

[image]

The problem now is that I actually don't know how to use it. I can guess that one side would be for debits and one side for credits (roughly circled in red in the image below), but I cannot tell which is which (neither basis the Hindi abbreviations, nor using the Gujarati abbreviations):

[image]

- I would be very grateful to someone who can explain the significance of, and right way to use, such a traditional *khata*.
- Secondly, can someone tell me if this is traditional, or whether this is just a marketing gimmick by printers to capitalize on the festival?

Comment: Welcome to HSE! The question might be closed as it does not relate to Hinduism and also comes under the category of personal advice questions. However just FYI, this is a cash book, the deposits (debits) must come on the ज side (left side) and the withdrawals (credits) must come on the ना side. You can have a look at: [help centre on asking questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi @Archit, thanks for the guidance, and I guess if the question is a little bit on the border of what might be acceptable here, but I would also think that the commercial lives & practices of Hindus would be an interesting area to explore on this site. Regardless, I wanted to clarify, you mean ज/deposits/_jama_ (?) are the credits right? And ना/withdrawals/_nikal_ (?) are the debits? Is there any reference to the Indian system of accounting/cash management that you might be aware of?

Comment: Haha, Yes, जमा on the left side is the deposit (incoming cash) and ना on the right side is the withdrawals (outgoing cash). Don’t get confused between debit credit, it will be bad. That’s why I’m not commenting on it. The debit credit status is what I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: On the other hand, the cover does rather recognise Diwali even every day, and the interval is from Diwali through Diwali :)